# When ag-grid OnGRIDReady is called?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

So this might appear a simple query and answer will be one-liner when the ag-grid is initialized :)

But I want to understand this in deeper detail than when exactly this will be triggered.

Because I have a small problem here at my end, I am logging component initialization to total data load time. And for a few requests, the time logged is quite high (say 10 sec) as compared to actual data load time from the backend ( which is in a few ms). This happens for few requests in the load scenario on production and not for all requests.

To me *OnGridReady* event seems to be the culprit which will be taking a long time to trigger in certain cases.
So what is **OnGridReady**  analysis, can it be triggered late from the client-side?

Here is the sample code for my use case:

```ts
     ngOnInit() {
            this.watcher.start();
            this.initGrid();
     }
    
     public initGrid() {
           this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
           ...
           this.gridOptions.onGridReady = () => {
                this.loadDataAndUpdateGRID();
            };
     } 

     private loadDataAndUpdateGRID(){
         this.service.getData() // taking only few miliseconds verified the api time
         .subscribe(response => {
             this.data = response;
             if (this.gridOptions.api) {
              this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.data);
              this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
             }
            this.watcher.log();
             },
            error => this.alertService.createAlert(error)
        );
     }
```

Comment: Your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), and is probably not answerable in its current state. The `onGridReady` event doesn't just randomly fire after 10 seconds. Try to make a demo that reproduces the problem, start from any Plunker example from [the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/).

Comment: I also experienced the problem described in the question. Unfortunately, it happens at random. I couldn't build a testcase that systematically reproduce it, so couldn't debug it.

Comment: It's not possible to help you without a test case (or even a full live site) to look at, even if it only happens sometimes. The first thing I would do is profile what's happening using the "Performance" tab in Chrome's Developer Tools.

Comment: For now i wanted to understand the behaviour of onGridReady so when is it initialized, is it possible that slow internet at user end can delay it?

Comment: @thirtydot as mentioned the problem happens for few requests in load scenario on production. so it is not readily reproducible and thus not straightforward, otherwise, I would have debugged it. at this point, I wanted more analysis of onGridReady behaviour.

Comment: Sure, CTRL+F for `dispatchGridReadyEvent` in [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/98c6c4554a4ef2c669ab0df42cf150f88ac72afa/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/grid.ts#L304). Does this help you? Likely not, which is why your question is an XY problem. Your real question is maybe about a possible ag-grid bug, and why it happens. Nobody can help without a reproduction (or a link to your production site), even if it only rarely happens. Good luck.